# Timepicker showing datepicker

Tags: jquery, datetimepicker, timepicker, jquery-ui-timepicker

I have added a timepicker js to my project and using the follwing code

```
$("#AcAppointments_start_time").timepicker({
                hourMin : 8,
              hourMax : 22,
              stepMinute : 15,
              timeOnly: true,
              timeFormat : "HH:mm"
        });
```

But whenever i am running the code, it is showing `datepicker` instead of `timepicker`, what may be the possible reason ?

Answer (score 1):

Check without those options like

```
$("#AcAppointments_start_time").timepicker();
```

And check initially it is working or not

Download js and css from [**THIS**](https://github.com/jonthornton/jquery-timepicker#timepicker-plugin-for-jquery)

Comment: I am getting the same problem yet

Comment: Then there is a problem with your js files that you are using

Comment: Download js and css from the link i have given and then try

Comment: I have replaced the timepicker-addon js file with the new downloaded file, yet getting the same problem :(

Comment: What are the other js files you have added before it..??

Comment: I have added jquery, jqueryui, and timepicker-ui-addon

Comment: Reomve that timepicker-ui-addon and add the new js file